# Connect MySQL with Grails project in Netbeans

Tags: mysql, grails, netbeans

I want to connect MySQL with Grails in Netbeans. I am using,

- Grails version:3.2
- Netbeans: 8.2
- JDK: 1.8
- OS: Windows 10

How to connect my grails project with MySQL Database in NetBeans? I have search through the internet, But could not find any way to add mysql-connector.jar or any other process.

How can I solve this problem?

Comment: This guide uses mysql http://guides.grails.org/creating-your-first-grails-app/guide/index.html

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you shouldn't add it manually. it is usually resolved (by convention) by adding proper dependency:

```
dependencies {
    runtime 'mysql:mysql-connector-java:5.1.29'
}
```

The configuration can be maintained in either **grails-app/conf/application.groovy** or **grails-app/conf/application.yml**

More info: https://docs.grails.org/latest/guide/conf.html#dataSource

Comment: Thanks.. I did this..and project compiled ...I have another question, Do i need to replace all the occurrence of H2 DB from build.gradle file with mysql?

Comment: yes, if you do not want to use h2 anymore. read whole `4.4 The DataSource`  section.

Comment: Thanks. I have configured like this. But still getting https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48148396/grail-project-is-not-excessing-mysql-db this error..Can you jelp me in this regard?