# Grails auto-generate the database from the domain model

Tags: mysql, grails, auto-generate

I am trying to create a simple application using Grails(3.2) and MySQL in Netbeans.
I have configured MySql in Grails project and also created a database, named "*third*" . After creating the domain class model, the controller (scaffolded) and the views for CRUD, my project is running but whenever I am trying to do any operation -
[screenshot of error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/K86aT.png)

this error is occuring. I am unable to solve this problem and also tried manually creating "*Person*" table, but same error occuring.

Comment: Are you running your app in dev mode? And how have you configured the db settings in application.yml?
Mine looks like this, and works:

`    environments:
         development:
             dataSource:
                 dbCreate: create-drop
                driverClassName: "com.mysql.jdbc.Driver"
                dialect: null
                url: "jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/yourDbName?autoreconnect=true&useSSL=false"
                username: "dbusername"
                password: "your-db-password"
                properties:
                   ...
`

Comment: I have followed https://docs.grails.org/latest/guide/conf.html#dataSource this process . 
Brother , I am new in grails. Can you help me out how to create simple crud in grails,mysql..I know laravel, but there is not so much tutorial for grails3 in internet.

Comment: Did you try the guide I gave you a link to on your previous question? http://guides.grails.org/creating-your-first-grails-app/guide/index.html

Answer (score 0):

Your stacktrace clearly states that your db with name *third* doesn't have proper table *person*. But **you shouldn't create this table manually** (if you already had - please remove all tables from your db)

Connection seems fine but you should take a look at **dbCreate** value in your **application.yml**.

> dbCreate - Whether to auto-generate the database from the domain model
>   - one of 'create-drop', 'create', 'update' or 'validate'

https://docs.grails.org/latest/guide/conf.html

If you are using just simple command `grails run-app` to start server, then you should check out the value in the **environments: development** block.

Paste your **application.yml** content (without db credentials) if you need a personalized solution.